# Postgres's serializable transaction blocks concurrent write

Tags: postgresql, transactions

In the [PostgreSQL's isolation levels documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/transaction-iso.html) it is stated that

> To guarantee true serializability PostgreSQL uses predicate locking,
>   which means that it keeps locks which allow it to determine when a
>   write would have had an impact on the result of a previous read from a
>   concurrent transaction, had it run first. In PostgreSQL these locks **do**
>   **not cause any blocking** and therefore can not play any part in causing
>   a deadlock. They are used to identify and flag dependencies among
>   concurrent Serializable transactions which in certain combinations can
>   lead to serialization anomalies.

When I try to execute two update statements in the isolation level `SERIALIZABLE`, it appears that the second write blocks until the first transaction commits or aborts. You can see the interaction int he gif file blow:

[image]

How does the about statement explain this behavior? I expected the second transaction continues until commit and then get `could not serialize` error.

BTW, the `event` table's schema is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE event (
  id INT,
  created_at timestamp
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paragraph describes only predicate locks, which are a special class of locks only used on the serializable isolation level.

Besides these special locks, a serializable transaction will also take the "normal" locks used by other isolation levels.

Comment: Thanks for clarification! A follow up question: can these locking (both in `SERIALIZABLE` and `REPEATABLE READ`) lead to deadlock or PostgreSQL will abort one of the transactions that is deadlocked?

Comment: You can get a deadlock, but PostgreSQL will resolve it by killing one of the transactions involved after waiting `deadlock_timeout` seconds (default 1).